# How to Get reference to HTML drop down after adding dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a `<select>` drop down to which I am adding values(countries) in `$(window).ready()` using this code:

```
$('#cmbCountry').append(new Option(el.Country, el.CountryID));
```

Later in my code I will try to set a value in drop down as

```
$("#cmbCountry").val(String("Italy"));
```

But its not setting the expected value as Dom doesn't know that the values has been added to drop down.

How can I solve this?

Comment: can  you show what html is genrated?

Comment: It should be `$("#cmbCountry").val("Italy");` I have't seen `String("Italy")` in JavaScript

Comment: <select id="cmbCountry" name="cmbCountry" style="width:100px">     <option value="0">-- Select --</option><option value="1">UK</option><option value="2">Italy</option></select>

Comment: You are trying to set the value with the name, not the real value. Try val(italyCountryID) with whatever the real id is, supposing you have it available

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#cmbCountry option:contains("Italy")').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the id (el.CountryID) as the value NOT the displayed string (el.Country).

This works:

```
var selectElem = $('<select/>');

selectElem.append(new Option("Italy", "it"));
selectElem.append(new Option("German", "de"));

selectElem.val('de'); // set 'de' as current value ('de' and NOT 'German'!)

$('body').append(selectElem);
```

Comment: My intention is to set based on value

Comment: Ok I understand, this isn't clear in your post. opatut's provided the solution.